# A tree data structure where every left node is greater than every right node in a max situation?

Tags: data-structures, tree, heap

Does such a tree exist and have a name, or is it just a figment of my imagination? I used to think heaps have this property but it just seems that the only requirement is for the children to be less than the parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's exactly the opposite, but you may be thinking of a [binary search tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree), which has the following properties:

> - The left subtree of a node contains only nodes with keys less than the node's key.
> - The right subtree of a node contains only nodes with keys greater than the node's key.
> - Both the left and right subtrees must also be binary search trees.
> - There must be no duplicate nodes.

So every left node is guaranteed to be less than every right node.  You can find the max by going right from the root node until you can't go right any more.